# Is there a standard way of classifying industries into primary, secondary, and tertiary?

Tags: industrial-organisation

For example, does any government (or academic) have a mapping from industry to sector. For example, mining is primary industry, and retail is tertiary, and so on...

Comment: I rarely see academic economists distinguishing between primary, secondary and tertiary. They usually use clear identification codes like NAICS (https://www.naics.com/search/ ) to refer to different industries.